# Username/PublicKey combination invalid error while loading data from EC2 to RedShift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, ssh-keys

While trying to load some data to Redshift from EC2 using COPY command, I am getting the below error.

```
ERROR: ErrorMessage: Username/PublicKey combination invalid ErrorCode: -18
```

I've added the public key of the Redshift cluster in the `authorized_keys` file of `ec2-user`. EC2 instance is running on AWS Linux2.

ssh_manifest file in S3 bucket is as below.

```
{ 
   "entries": [ 
     {"endpoint":"<public ip of ec2>", 
       "command": "cat test_users_pipe.txt",
       "mandatory":true, 
       "username": "ec2-user"}
    ] 
}
```

And below is the COPY command.

```
copy test2_users
from '<s3-bucket-uri>/ssh_manifest'
credentials 'aws_iam_role=<role_arn>'
delimited '|' region '<aws_region>'
ssh;
```